# What is the difference between setting sourceMap in tsconfig and in angular.json

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to enable source maps for the production build target in an angular workspace for debugging purposes.

I have set in the `tsconfig.json`

```
"sourceMap": true
```

This did not give the source maps in Chrome's Dev Tools.

Setting it in the `angular.json` as below works

```
{
      "build": {
        ...
        "configurations": {
          "prod": {
            "sourceMap": true
            ...
          }
          ...
        }
      }
    }
```

Why did it not work when enabling the source maps via the tsconfig?

Is it because Angular has its own special compiler/transpiler that handles Angular specific code like decorators, template code etc.?

**Update**

I have disabled `sourceMap` in the tsconfig.json and enabled it only in `angular.json`. I do get the source maps when I build the app.

What am I misunderstanding?